# Is it possible to run Kismet without WebUI / webserver?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, debian

I want to use Kismet on a lightweight system.
For this reason I would like to start Kismet without the new WebUI, implemented since Kismet 2019-04.
Are there any possibilities to prevent kismet from starting with webserver?

Answer (score 0):

There is no option to disable it at runtime, so far.

I am said it will not use that much cpu and RAM.

You can look at the  [Performance and memory](https://www.kismetwireless.net/docs/readme/performance_and_memory/) doc page of kismet.

There is some option available in the configuration of kismet.
And one only option at compile time is to disable typesafety checking.

Answer (score -1):

You can download the legacy Kismet-2016-07-R1 release here:

https://www.kismetwireless.net/code/kismet-2016-07-R1.tar.xz

I dont need the WEB UI ...

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I need the never version.